# New table view cell shows as a blank cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've been working on an app, and ran into some problems, so I rebuilt it as simple as possible to find where the error happens at. My code uses CoreData, and my first example has the code for adding new items inside the plus button in the navigation bar. In other words, there is no change of view or segue. This version works as I would expect it to. See the following GIF.

[image]

But when I make a new view controller that adds the new item, I end up getting a blank cell instead. I have the exact same code behind the add button that I had in the plus button. And I just use a show segue to get from the tableview to a normal view controller. But if I quit the app and start it back up, it all shows correctly. See below.

[image]

If you are curious, I have the section it is adding to being a random number between 1 and 3. My guess is there is something I need to do with that segue but I don't have clue what it is. I'm very new at Swift so I have lots to learn.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me. I think if I can solve this problem, I can finally move forward with developing my app. Thank you again. Below is my code for the case where it has a segue.

Table View Controller Code (Swift)

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ListItemsTVC: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

// MARK: - Constants and Variables

let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

// MARK: - App loading Functions

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    frc = getFCR()
    frc.delegate = self

    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print("Failed to perform inital fetch")
    }
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 62

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Outlets and Actions

/*@IBAction func addItem(sender: AnyObject) {

    let entityDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Items", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
    let item = Items(entity: entityDesc!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)

    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("nextItemID") == nil) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(1, forKey: "nextItemID")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    let id = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("nextItemID")

    item.id = id
    switch id {
    case 1...9:
        item.name = "Item ID: 0\(id)"
    default:
        item.name = "Item ID: \(id)"
    }
    item.brand = "Brand \(id)"
    item.qty = 1
    item.price = 0
    item.size = "Size \(id)"
    let sec: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4 - 1))) + 1
    item.section = "Section \(sec)"
    item.isChecked = false

    do {
        try moc.save()
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(id + 1, forKey: "nextItemID")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    } catch {
        fatalError("New item save failed")
    }

}*/

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if let sections = frc.sections {
        return sections.count
    }

    return 0

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if let sections = frc.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        return currentSection.numberOfObjects
    }

    return 0

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 28

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    if let sections = frc.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        return currentSection.name
    }

    return nil

}

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

    tableView.beginUpdates()

}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

    tableView.endUpdates()

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("listContentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListItemsTVCell
    let item = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Items

    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 78, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    cell.itemName.text = item.name
    cell.itemSection.text = item.section
    cell.itemQty.text = "Qty: \(item.qty!)"
    cell.itemSize.text = item.size
    cell.itemPrice.text = floatToCurrency(Float(item.price!))
    //cell.itemImage.image = UIImage(data: item.image!)
    cell.itemID.text = String(item.id!)

    return cell

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in

        let item = self.frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Items
        let id = item.id!
        let request = self.fetchRequest()
        let pred = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "id",id)
        request.predicate = pred
        var fetchResults = [AnyObject]()

        do {
            fetchResults = try self.moc.executeFetchRequest(request)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Fetching Data to Delete Failed")
        }

        self.moc.deleteObject(fetchResults[0] as! NSManagedObject)
        fetchResults.removeAtIndex(0)

        do {
            try self.moc.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to Save after Delete")
        }

    }

    return [delete]

}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        /*case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
         tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)*/
    default:
        print("Default in didChangeSection was called")
        break
    }

}

internal func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    default:
        print("Default in didChangeObject was called")
        break
    }

}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

/*

// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

// MARK: - Custom Functions

func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Items")
    let sortDesc1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "section", ascending: true)
    let sortDesc2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "isChecked", ascending: true)
    let sortDesc3 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc1, sortDesc2, sortDesc3]

    return fetchRequest

}

func getFCR() -> NSFetchedResultsController {

    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "section" , cacheName: nil)

    return frc

}

func floatToCurrency(flt: Float) -> String {

    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    return String(formatter.stringFromNumber(flt)!)

}

}
```

View Controller (Swift) [The segue view]

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddItemListVC: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

// MARK: - Constants and Variables

let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
//var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

// MARK: - App loading Functions

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Outlets and Actions

@IBAction func addItem(sender: AnyObject) {

    let entityDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Items", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
    let item = Items(entity: entityDesc!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)

    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("nextItemID") == nil) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(1, forKey: "nextItemID")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    let id = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("nextItemID")

    item.id = id
    switch id {
    case 1...9:
        item.name = "Item ID: 0\(id)"
    default:
        item.name = "Item ID: \(id)"
    }
    item.brand = "Brand \(id)"
    item.qty = 1
    item.price = 0
    item.size = "Size \(id)"
    let sec: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4 - 1))) + 1
    item.section = "Section \(sec)"
    item.isChecked = false

    do {
        try moc.save()
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(id + 1, forKey: "nextItemID")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    } catch {
        fatalError("New item save failed")
    }

}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Comment: fetch data in view will appear method and reload tableview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload TableView Data is `viewWillAppear` method as :

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print("Failed to perform inital fetch")
    }
}
```

As when you are navigating back from `viewController` you are not telling the `TableViewController` to update tableView so do it in viewWillAppear as it will fire when you are popping navController to come back.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work for me. I'm still experiencing the same issue of the cell showing as blank. To be clear, I tried taking the code out of viewDidLoad and put it inside of viewWillAppear, and at the end of that, put self.tableView.reloadData(). But got the same problem. I also played around with having the code in both viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear, putting self.tableView.reloadData() in various places (beginning and ending) but all give me the same event. A blank cell when hitting the back button.

Comment: Can you put break point in viewWillAppear to check if its coming there and in getFcr to check if the newly added item is in the list or not ?

Comment: You know, literally, after adding my comment I tried one other option, and that seems to have made it work. I'm not sure if you were trying to say that all along and I misunderstood. But I kept my code exactly the same as above. But added in inside of viewWillAppear the reloadData() and nothing else. And it now works. I'll add in my new code as a second answer to this.

Comment: A warning to anyone trying to use this as a solution for a similar problem. This fix only works intermittently. It will sometimes load the cell and sometime load the cell as blank. I checked to make sure that reloadData() is being run every time and it appears that it is. So I'm not sure what the problem is, but it doesn't appear to be solely with viewWillAppear.

Comment: @JasonBrady have a look at the below answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that fixed the problem for me. I only changed the Table View Controller Code:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ListItemsTVC: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

// MARK: - Constants and Variables

let moc = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
var frc: NSFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController()

// MARK: - App loading Functions

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    frc = getFCR()
    frc.delegate = self

    do {
        try frc.performFetch()
    } catch {
        print("Failed to perform inital fetch")
    }
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 62

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Outlets and Actions

/*@IBAction func addItem(sender: AnyObject) {

    let entityDesc = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Items", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
    let item = Items(entity: entityDesc!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc)

    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("nextItemID") == nil) {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(1, forKey: "nextItemID")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    let id = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("nextItemID")

    item.id = id
    switch id {
    case 1...9:
        item.name = "Item ID: 0\(id)"
    default:
        item.name = "Item ID: \(id)"
    }
    item.brand = "Brand \(id)"
    item.qty = 1
    item.price = 0
    item.size = "Size \(id)"
    let sec: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4 - 1))) + 1
    item.section = "Section \(sec)"
    item.isChecked = false

    do {
        try moc.save()
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(id + 1, forKey: "nextItemID")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    } catch {
        fatalError("New item save failed")
    }

}*/

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    if let sections = frc.sections {
        return sections.count
    }

    return 0

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if let sections = frc.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        return currentSection.numberOfObjects
    }

    return 0

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    return 28

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    if let sections = frc.sections {
        let currentSection = sections[section]
        return currentSection.name
    }

    return nil

}

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

    tableView.beginUpdates()

}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {

    tableView.endUpdates()

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("listContentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ListItemsTVCell
    let item = frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Items

    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 78, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    cell.itemName.text = item.name
    cell.itemSection.text = item.section
    cell.itemQty.text = "Qty: \(item.qty!)"
    cell.itemSize.text = item.size
    cell.itemPrice.text = floatToCurrency(Float(item.price!))
    //cell.itemImage.image = UIImage(data: item.image!)
    cell.itemID.text = String(item.id!)

    return cell

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, indexPath) in

        let item = self.frc.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Items
        let id = item.id!
        let request = self.fetchRequest()
        let pred = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", "id",id)
        request.predicate = pred
        var fetchResults = [AnyObject]()

        do {
            fetchResults = try self.moc.executeFetchRequest(request)
        } catch {
            fatalError("Fetching Data to Delete Failed")
        }

        self.moc.deleteObject(fetchResults[0] as! NSManagedObject)
        fetchResults.removeAtIndex(0)

        do {
            try self.moc.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to Save after Delete")
        }

    }

    return [delete]

}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        self.tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        /*case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Update:
         tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)*/
    default:
        print("Default in didChangeSection was called")
        break
    }

}

internal func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {

    switch type {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Delete:
        self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeType.Insert:
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
    default:
        print("Default in didChangeObject was called")
        break
    }

}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
*/

/*

// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

// MARK: - Custom Functions

func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Items")
    let sortDesc1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "section", ascending: true)
    let sortDesc2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "isChecked", ascending: true)
    let sortDesc3 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDesc1, sortDesc2, sortDesc3]

    return fetchRequest

}

func getFCR() -> NSFetchedResultsController {

    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "section" , cacheName: nil)

    return frc

}

func floatToCurrency(flt: Float) -> String {

    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    return String(formatter.stringFromNumber(flt)!)

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad's answer will surely solve the problem as it will trigger the reload of the table view every time viewWillAppear will call. But the problem is that is not a very good way of doing this.

You see, `viewWillAppear` gets called a lot of times. It is a UIViewController life cycle method. If you are going to the second view controller and coming back without pressing the add button, it will still reload the UITableView. Now, the point is not whether it is an expensive operation or not, the point is that `viewWillAppear` is not the place to do that kind of a stuff. What if you had to do something else before reloading the cell, you may not want to put it all there and risk creating bugs.

A good way of achieving this is through delegates (call backs). Read up more on this and you will see that it gives you a much needed flexibility.