# NSFetchedResultsController saving data but UITableView not configuring cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

When returning from a ViewController where I add and save an NSManagedObject, the TableView inserts a blank cell where the new cell should be. If I back out from the tableview screen and go back, it reloads and configures everything properly.

So what I know from this is that the data is being properly saved to the store, I know the FRC delegate operations are all being called (.Insert, for instance), and I actually can see via breakpoints that my "configureCell" method is being called and is passing back a fully configured cell. The tableview is just putting in a blank one instead.

I can post code if you'd like, but I was just curious if this description rang any bells for anyone? I've been researching this problem off and on for weeks but haven't really found anything similar.

For troubleshooting purposes I:

1. took my custom UITableViewCell out of the mix and just had the tableview configure a generic cell... didn't help.
2. created a stripped-down version of the app flow in another project, including core data, FRC, custom tableview cell, etc... this actually DOESN'T display the same behavior. I've compared the two projects side by side and can't determine any meaningful difference (other than the data itself that's being displayed).
3. I've even gone so far as to insert a delay between the context.save() operation and dismissing the VC where I create the object, just to see if it's some sort of race condition between when the object is created and when the table configures the cell. Needless to say, that did nothing.

Is this a bug anyone else has encountered? Anyone seen this behavior before?

Thanks in advance, sorry for the wall but this is something that Google, various subreddits, and so far StackOverflow has not been able to help me with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after rephrasing my question I found this from back in May.

[New table view cell shows as a blank cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994649/new-table-view-cell-shows-as-a-blank-cell)

No solution there, but I reached out to him via twitter and his suggestion worked. Switching my size class back to any/any seems to have solved the problem, which means this might be an autolayout bug. It needs more testing but I think I've done everything that would demonstrate the issue and I think it's resolved.

Comment: Hello i'm having the same issue. How did you solve it? I'm not using Storyboards

Comment: In my case it was changing size classes, but the author of the post I link to above also posted his own answer as a comment to the original question, maybe that would help you?